# C String spliting into array, bad behaviour when string is not supposed to be split

Tags: arrays, c, string, split, strdup

when input has "|" the string splits normally, when str does not have "|" it seg faults

```
char **cmds;

if (strchr(input, '|'))
    cmds = split(input,'|');
else
    cmds[0] = strdup(input);
```

Comment: You don't have room to store `strdup(input);`, call `cmds = malloc(sizeof *cmds);` before `cmds[0] = strdup(input);`, don't forget to call `free(cmds);` when no longer needed.

Comment: @DanielMarcelinoSequeira Don't worry.  If you keep writing C, it won't be your last one.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate an array to store the pointer:

```
cmds = malloc(sizeof(*cmds));
cmds[0] = strdup(input);
```